# How to send images from one domain to other domain hosted on different servers

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I am working on a web app which give utility to users to share photos to other Selected websites. i know much about it and at current time, i am sending images as base64 string because i have not htaccess for other domain to which photos will be sent.

Problem is there if i send photo through ajax than cross domain error occurs, if i give action url then a tab open with action url. i have to restrict action on same page without reloading.

how can i send images to other domains with ajax without htaccess access.

I can just give one php page which they will upload in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give target for action in form where you uploading images.

Target a iframe which have negligible height width at some position of the page. by this way you can upload images without refreshing page and no htaccess access required.

Tick as correct answer if it really helping.